# Kubernetes logs with label selector does not work for some labeles

Tags: logging, kubernetes, label

When retrieving the logs using `kubectl logs -l`, it returns the logs for some of the labels, but it does not return anything for some other labels.

For example:

```
~/ $ kubectl logs -n test -lapp=testapp
~/ $ kubectl logs -n test -lapp.kubernetes.io/instance=test
2019-07-30 15:28:39.913  INFO 1 ---
```

The labels of the `deployment`:

```
~/ $ kubectl get deployments.apps -n test --show-labels 
NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     LABELS
testapp                 1/1     1            1           55m     app.kubernetes.io/instance=test,app=testapp
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you verify [paulogrell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57276117/kubernetes-logs-with-label-selector-does-not-work-for-some-labeles/57279204#57279204) suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure both the deployment and template labels are properly set.

```
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "testapp",
          "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "test"
        }
      },
```

You can use:

- kubectl logs --selector app.kubernetes.io/instance=test
- kubectl logs -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=test

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it was fixed after I added the label to the template.